# I am not able to run my program due to update of android studio and adb.exe

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, updates

Cannot run program 
`"C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=2,`

The system cannot find the file specified 
This error is showing when I start the update and I can't run the program too?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the app
you can try this.

Open command window

```
cd C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.temp\PackageOperation01
```

Click enter
Type adb nodaemon server
Click enter
Let me know if it works